# Review Suspension not in FAQ

Tags: feature-request, review, faq-suggestion

So apparently, I've been suspended from reviews by some [automatic process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban) of which I was completely unaware. Due to there being absolutely nothing about review suspension in the FAQ, I understand very little about this. Could we fix that, please? Something this integral to the day-in, day-out working of the site ought to be a bit more front-and-center. Also, being suspended without any idea of how to improve my reviews isn't helpful, either. I'm not just trying to pass junk through to get a badge - I actually want to do good reviews. So help me do this, please!

One thing that would be especially helpful is a (probably non-exhaustive) checklist of things to watch out for in reviewing.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking for a feature, so could someone please add that tag as well? Thanks!

Comment: No, you haven't been suspended from review. You would get a message if you had been. A recent change (like yesterday) makes review now require 500 reputation. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark/ and downvote if you disagree ;)

Comment: 500 rep for that privilege sounds fine. I think there ought to be a significant amount of material on training users in so that they know the most-frequent offenders, that sort of thing.

Comment: @Seth: Your comment is really the answer to my question. I'll +1 it if you convert it to an answer.

Comment: I'll add an answer later.

Answer (score 3):

### You weren't suspended,

you just don't have enough reputation to review posts. If you visit [askubuntu.com/review](http://asuspenedskubuntu.com/review) you will see:

[image]

There was a recent change, raising the rep requirement to review from 125 to 500; hence the reason you could review yesterday and not today. For more information on the change see [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark/)

I personally think this was an awful change....

### On the review audit subject..

You *do* get a notification if you have been banned from review, on sites where review audits are enabled. Audit aren't actually enabled on Ask Ubuntu. You also get a message for each passed and failed review audit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the mobile site atm, so can't get to the right screen to corroborate what I'm saying, but I would say this is happening because you're failing audits.

Every so often you'll be thrown a question that was already dealt with by other users. If you don't come to the same decision, it'll count as a fail.

Fall too many times and you'll be suspended. It makes sense if you think about it but I agree, it should be more explicit about what you failed and what others did.

I rather thought it did tell you when you fall an audit post (after, obviously). Keep an eye out for feedback when you next review things.

Comment: Nope, as Seth notes in the comments, a new change has rolled out that raised the rep requirement for review 4-fold.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I didn't realize that there actually were review audits until last month. They seem relatively secret and some transparency would be helpful. It would be a really nice feature to know when users have actually passed those audits. Perhaps a badge for passing a number of these?

Comment: @maggotbrain There aren't any audits on AU. AFAIK they are only enabled on the trilogy.

Comment: Wait, so review audits *and* making /review require 500?! man, changes.

Comment: @Seth hmmm. ok. According to a comment on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) "currently they(audits) are active on Stack Overflow, Super User, Programmers and Server Fault." It took awhile to track this down. I can't find a definitive statement anywhere else so far. Anyone else?

Comment: @maggotbrain I don't remember the source, but they aren't enabled on AU. I know that.  Also,  you do get notified when you pass audits *and* when you fail them. I know that by personal experience on other sites.